# Which would be better for a load balancer: HAProxy or Nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, haproxy, round-robin

Node.js is having some serious issues performing under high concurrency, managing streams and delivering 'data' events correctly. So horizontal scaling seems like the best solution, to keep alive several instances of the same application.

After some research, I cannot decide yet, which would be better for a least_conn, or round robin load balancer.

If anyone has had experience using both and, keeping in mind it has to work with Node V: 0.12.0,

Which of both would be a better load balancer / TCP proxy manager in terms of reliability and performance wise?

Comment: they are both good - if all you want is a load balancer and not a web server, try HA Proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct answer is "It depends" but i'm biased to use specialized solutions. In this case HAProxy is the specialized solution for your problem. There is even a hardware appliance based on it.